# How can I tell what woke my laptop from suspend?

Tags: linux, laptop, suspend

On other operating systems, there are ways to see what process or event woke them from suspend. I leave my laptop often for multiple days in suspend, sometimes to find that it has woken itself up and is heating whatever surface it is resting on :)

Is there a way to find out what woke it up so that I can prevent that thing from happening again? On Ubuntu 12.04 (elementary Luna).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I'm aware of that's commonly used to force a wake (besides, I guess, the hardware interrupts) is the `rtcwake` command.  The source for that uses `ioctl()` calls on the real time clock device (by default, `/dev/rtc0`) meaning it must have privileges (so it cannot be anything you start on your desktop as a normal user).

I would be very surprised to learn that there is a privileged service on Ubuntu set up to do anything like that (why?).  However, I do notice that *occasionally* a sleeping system has woken up for no apparent reason while left alone. I do not have a cat, so I  assume this is something having vibrated the mouse, or maybe some weird voltage fluctuation, or some other random cause.

If this happens regularly, it may indicate a bug in the ACPI driver.

Comment: Same here, it's only occasionally. I don't have a cat or a mouse attached, so it must be something weird.